# How can i detect error from code behind to create a custom error page without using web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I'm trying to detect error 404 and display a custom error page when it occurs using code behind in asp.net and not web.config. the code is not working, it just gives the default error page.
this is my code:

```
Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
HttpException httpException = (HttpException)exception;
Server.ClearError();

if (httpException.ErrorCode == 404)
{
    Response.Redirect("Page_Not_Found.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Why not configuring it through web.config file?

Comment: i added an else statement so that any error that is not 404 will direct the user to the same page and will send an email to the administrator. this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be to handle it through `web.confng` like following.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/UnexpectedError.html">
  <error redirect="~/404Error.html" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: How could you answer that question 2min after its closing?

Comment: i added an else statement so that any error that is not 404 will direct the user to the same page and will send an email to the administrator. so this will not work.

Comment: Not sure.. I just started writing and in between question was closed.